# codeschool emberjs 7.4 rating a product not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, fixtures

I have been battling the level 7.4 review question with no luck:

> Rating isn’t a object like Review was, so our createRating function will be a little different. We can addObject the currently selected rating to the array of ratings on our product. You’ll need to save the product to update it in the store.

I can not seem to get the value from the select list.  Can anyone point me in the right direction or collaborate on this?

My handlebars code:

```
  <script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='product'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm-7'>
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <h3 class='text-success'>${{price}}</h3>
        <p class='text-muted'>{{description}}</p>
        <p class='text-muted'>This Product has a {{rating}} star rating!</p>
        <p>Finely crafted by {{#link-to 'contact' crafter}}{{crafter.name}}{{/link-to}}.</p>
        {{render 'reviews' reviews}}
        <div class='new-rating'>
          <h3>Rate {{title}}</h3>

        </div>
        <div class='new-review'>
          <h3>Review {{title}}</h3>
          {{#if text}}
            <p class='text-muted'>{{text}}</p>
          {{/if}}
          {{textarea valueBinding='text'}}
          <button {{action 'createReview'}} class='btn-primary'>Review</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-5'>
        <img {{bind-attr src='image'}} class='img-thumbnail img-rounded'/>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{contact-details contact=crafter className='row'}}



     {{view Ember.Select content=ratings value=selectedRating}}
    <button {{action 'createRating'}} class='btn-primary'>Rating</button>
  </script>
```

My js code:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('credits', { path: '/thanks' });
  this.resource('products', function() {
    this.resource('product', { path: '/:product_id' });
    this.route('onsale');
    this.route('deals');
  });
  this.resource('contacts', function() {
    this.resource('contact', { path: '/:contact_id' });
  });
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  productsCount: Ember.computed.alias('length'),
  logo: 'images/logo-small.png',
  time: function() {
    return (new Date()).toDateString();
  }.property(),
  onSale: function() {
    return this.filterBy('isOnSale').slice(0,3);
  }.property('@each.isOnSale')
});
App.ContactsIndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  contactName: 'Anostagia',
  avatar: 'images/avatar.png',
  open: function() {
    return ((new Date()).getDay() === 0) ? "Closed" : "Open";
  }.property()
});
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['title']
});
App.ContactsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['name'],
  contactsCount: Ember.computed.alias('length')
});
App.ReviewsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['reviewedAt'],
  sortAscending: false
});
App.ContactProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['title']
});
App.ProductController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  text: '',
  ratings: [1,2,3,4,5],
  selectedRating: 5,
  actions: {
    createReview: function(){
      var review = this.store.createRecord('review', {
        text: this.get('text'),
        product: this.get('model'),
        reviewedAt: new Date()
      });
      var controller = this;
      review.save().then(function() {
        controller.set('text', '');
        controller.get('model.reviews').addObject(review);
      });
    },
    createRating: function(){
      var rating = this.store.createRecord('rating', {
        rating: this.get('selectedRating.value'),
        product: this.get('model'),
        reviewedAt: new Date()
      });
      var controller = this;
      rating.save().then(function() {
        controller.get('model.rating').addObject(rating);
      });
    }
  }
});

App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('product');
  }
});
App.ContactsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('contact');
  }
});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.findAll('product');
  }
});
App.ProductsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.findAll('product');
  }
});
App.ProductsOnsaleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.modelFor('products').filterBy('isOnSale');
  }
});
App.ProductsDealsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.modelFor('products').filter(function(product){
      return product.get('price') < 500;
    });
  }
});

App.ProductDetailsComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
 reviewsCount: Ember.computed.alias('product.reviews.length'),
  hasReviews: function(){
    return this.get('reviewsCount') > 0;
  }.property('reviewsCount')
});
App.ContactDetailsComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  productsCount: Ember.computed.alias('contact.products.length'),
  isProductive: function() {
    return this.get('productsCount') > 3;
  }.property('productsCount')
});

App.ProductView = Ember.View.extend({
  isOnSale: Ember.computed.alias('controller.isOnSale'),
  classNameBindings: ['isOnSale']
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  price: DS.attr('number'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  isOnSale: DS.attr('boolean'),
  image: DS.attr('string'),
  reviews: DS.hasMany('review', { async: true }),
  crafter: DS.belongsTo('contact', { async: true }),
  ratings: DS.attr(),
  rating: function(){
    return this.get('ratings').reduce(function(previousValue, rating) {
      return previousValue + rating;
    }, 0) / this.get('ratings').length;
  }.property('ratings.@each')
});

App.Product.FIXTURES = [
 {  id: 1,
    title: 'Flint',
    price: 99,
    description: 'Flint is a hard, sedimentary cryptocrystalline form of the mineral quartz, categorized as a variety of chert.',
    isOnSale: true,
    image: 'images/products/flint.png',
    reviews: [100,101],
    crafter: 200,
    ratings: [2,1,3,3]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Kindling',
    price: 249,
    description: 'Easily combustible small sticks or twigs used for starting a fire.',
    isOnSale: false,
    image: 'images/products/kindling.png',
    reviews: [],
    crafter: 201,
    ratings: [2,1,3,3]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Matches',
    price: 499,
    description: 'One end is coated with a material that can be ignited by frictional heat generated by striking the match against a suitable surface.',
    isOnSale: true,
    reviews: [],
    image: 'images/products/matches.png',
    crafter: 201,
    ratings: [2,1,3,3]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Bow Drill',
    price: 999,
    description: 'The bow drill is an ancient tool. While it was usually used to make fire, it was also used for primitive woodworking and dentistry.',
    isOnSale: false,
    reviews: [],
    image: 'images/products/bow-drill.png',
    crafter: 200,
    ratings: [1,3,3]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'Tinder',
    price: 499,
    description: 'Tinder is easily combustible material used to ignite fires by rudimentary methods.',
    isOnSale: true,
    reviews: [],
    image: 'images/products/tinder.png',
    crafter: 201,
    ratings: [2,1,3]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: 'Birch Bark Shaving',
    price: 999,
    description: 'Fresh and easily combustable',
    isOnSale: true,
    reviews: [],
    image: 'images/products/birch.png',
    crafter: 201,
    ratings: [2,3,5]
  }
];

App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  about: DS.attr('string'),
  avatar: DS.attr('string'),
  products: DS.hasMany('product', { async: true })
});
App.Contact.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 200,
    name: 'Giamia',
    about: 'Although Giamia came from a humble spark of lightning, he quickly grew to be a great craftsman, providing all the warming instruments needed by those close to him.',
    avatar: 'images/contacts/giamia.png',
    products: [1,4]
  },
  {
    id: 201,
    name: 'Anostagia',
    about: 'Knowing there was a need for it, Anostagia drew on her experience and spearheaded the Flint & Flame storefront. In addition to coding the site, she also creates a few products available in the store.',
    avatar: 'images/contacts/anostagia.png',
    products: [2,3,5,6]
  }
];

App.Review = DS.Model.extend({
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  reviewedAt: DS.attr('date'),
  product: DS.belongsTo('product')
});
App.Review.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 100, 
    text: "Started a fire in no time!"
  },
  {
    id: 101, 
    text: "Not the brightest flame, but warm!"
  }
];
```

Comment: In which template does that handlebars exist?

Comment: @kingpin2k I just added the hbs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After detailed research, the answer turned out being:

```
createRating: function() {
      var prod = this.get('model');
      var ratings = this.get('model.ratings');
      ratings.addObject(this.selectedRating);
      prod.save();
    }
```

Comment: you should probably still use a getter on it, but glad you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the code shown, you should be getting the rating using `this.get('selectedRating')` not `this.get('selectedRating.value')`

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xohidixe/1/edit

Comment: the only answer it accepted was the one I posted above. thank you for your help :)